# How to populate mobx-state-tree map from existing object

Tags: typescript, mobx-state-tree

This is a simplified version of my Store. I want to initialise it with data coming from json.

However, typescript keeps bothering me with errors.

```js
const DistrictModel = types.model('District', {
  id: types.string,
  name: types.string,
  borders: types.array(types.string),
  owner: 0,
})

interface IDistrictModel extends Instance<typeof DistrictModel> {}

const Store = types.model({
  mapId: types.string,
  districts: types.map(DistrictModel),
})

interface IStore extends Instance<typeof Store> {}


// Imported from mapdata.json

const mapData = {
  "id": "testmap",
  "districts": {
    "topleft": { "name": "topleft", "borders": ["topright", "bottomleft"] },
    "topright": { "name": "topright", "borders": ["bottomright", "topleft"] },
  }
}

const createStore = (): IStore => {
  const store = Store.create({
    mapId: mapData.id,
    // Also tried with <string, IDistrictModel> to make it more readable
    districts: new Map(
      Object.entries(mapData.districts).map(([id, district]) => [
        id,
        DistrictModel.create({ id, ...district }),
      ]),
    ),
  })

  return store
}
```

Typescript says:

`Type 'Map<string, { id: string; name: string; borders: IMSTArray<ISimpleType<string>> & IStateTreeNode<IArrayType<ISimpleType<string>>>; owner: number; } & NonEmptyObject & IStateTreeNode<...>>' is not assignable to type 'IKeyValueMap<ModelCreationType<ExtractCFromProps<{ id: ISimpleType<string>; name: ISimpleType<string>; borders: IArrayType<ISimpleType<string>>; owner: IType<number | undefined, number, number>; }>>>'.`

`Index signature is missing in type 'Map<string, { id: string; name: string; borders: IMSTArray<ISimpleType<string>> & IStateTreeNode<IArrayType<ISimpleType<string>>>; owner: number; } & NonEmptyObject & IStateTreeNode<...>>'.`

I find it very hard to read this kind of typescript errors, so I have trouble figuring out what is wrong.
I have tried making it more readable with `new Map<string, IDistrictModel>`. This results in:

`Type 'Map<string, IDistrictModel>' is not assignable to type 'IKeyValueMap<ModelCreationType<ExtractCFromProps<{ id: ISimpleType<string>; name: ISimpleType<string>; borders: IArrayType<ISimpleType<string>>; owner: IType<number | undefined, number, number>; }>>>'.`

`Index signature is missing in type 'Map<string, IDistrictModel>'.`

It seems an MST map can't be initialised with an actual new Map.

Can anyone help out?

**EDIT**

Example sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mst-typescript-ji8ol?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Could you please share reproducable example ?

Comment: [Your code seems to be working nicely](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-tereshkova-wgpei?file=/src/index.ts) if you change `id` to `mapId` in your `mapData` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your example Tholle. I see it seems to work when passing in an object with the same props. But what if some data comes from somewhere else - so aggregate data from `mapdata.json` and some other source in the create function.
I would like to understand why I can't pass in a `new Map`.

Comment: To clarify further, the current reason I'm modifying the object is because I want to copy the object key into the value as `id` prop.

Answer (score 2):

@Tholle's comment made me realise that even even though `districts` in MST is declared as a `Map` you can't "fill" it with `new Map()`.
One actually needs to pass in an object literal to feed an MST map in the create function.

It's not very functional (at all...), but with the below code I did get it to work.

```js
const createStore = (): IStore => {
  const districts: { [k: string]: any } = {}

  for (const [key, district] of Object.entries(mapData.districts)) {
    districts[key] = { id: key, ...district }
  }

  return GameStore.create({
    mapId: mapData.id,
    districts,
  })
}
```